# HA Proxy rewrite and redirect

Tags: haproxy

Trying to do a rewrite and redirect. I've been trying this, it works to some extent but not 100% what I want it to do

acl old url_beg /site/ab
http-request redirect location /new/%[query] if old

the url can be for example

- https://host/site/ab/**xx**
- https://host/site/ab/**yyyy**
- https://host/site/ab/**zzzzzz**
- https://host/site/ab/**zzzzzz**/asdajshdjasd

I am looking to grab the bold marked part and simply redirect the user to https//host/new/**boldmarkedpart**

Any string that comes after the bold marked part can be trashed. For example "/asdajshdjasd" in the last example.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to split the `path` part of `url` and get its 4th part.
In string `foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4/foo5` you want only `foo4`.
This should work for you:

```
acl old path_beg /site/ab
http-request redirect location /new/%[path,field(4,/)] if old
```

It may be confusing that you want 3rd directory from path and here you take 4th word, but that's because when you split `/foo2/foo3/foo4/foo5` by `/` then the first word is empty.
`field` converter is documented here: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#7.3.1-field

Other notes:

- `%[query]` would return the `query` part of `url`, which is everything after `?` character and you don't have query part at all in your examples.
- `url` in my tests had `schema://hostname:port/path`, so testing `acl old url_beg /site/ab` never matched, `path` is for that